# InAppBrowser event handlers aren't firing: Ionic 5 + Angular 10 + Capacitor

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, subscribe

Here's code I added to a `blank` Angular+Capacitor starter project produced by Ionic's CLI (within `home.page.ts`):

```
  openInAppBrowser() {
    const exampleUrl = 'https://ionicframework.com/docs/components';
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      usewkwebview: 'yes'
    };
    const browser = this.iab.create(exampleUrl, '_blank', options);
    const eventTypes: InAppBrowserEventType[] = ['loadstart', 'loadstop', 'beforeload', 'exit', 'loaderror'];
    eventTypes.forEach(eventType => {
      browser.on(eventType).subscribe(event => {
        console.log(`Event ${eventType} fired!`); // Doesn't get here
        console.log(`URL: [${event.url}]`);       // or here (obviously).
        if (event.url && event.url.includes('path-i-am-interested-in')) {
          // Do useful stuff...
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(`Browser object after subscription:`);
    console.log(browser);
  }
```

When I deploy this to an iPhone 11 simulator or tethered to my iPhone 11 through XCode, none of the `console.log` calls fire within the listener.

I built an Ionic-Vue project with this code, and it works fine.  Why doesn't this work with Angular?

Here's the pared-down repo with the full implementation:
https://bitbucket.org/aaronw322/ionic-inappbrowser-subscription/src/master/

The README outlines the steps I took to install/build it.

Here are the logs from XCode's console after opening the InAppBrowser example site, clicking links, then pressing `Done` in the bottom corner of the InAppBrowser window (notice that none of the desired log output is shown):

```
To Native Cordova ->  InAppBrowser open InAppBrowser694511092 ["options": [https://ionicframework.com/docs/components, _blank, usewkwebview=yes]]
2020-11-07 09:26:23.859892-0500 App[22260:325714] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-11-07 09:26:23.860064-0500 App[22260:325714] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
⚡️  [log] - Browser object after subscription:
⚡️  [log] - {"_objectInstance":{"channels":{"beforeload":{"type":"beforeload","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":1,"onHasSubscribersChange":null},"loadstart":{"type":"loadstart","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":1,"onHasSubscribersChange":null},"loadstop":{"type":"loadstop","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":1,"onHasSubscribersChange":null},"loaderror":{"type":"loaderror","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":1,"onHasSubscribersChange":null},"exit":{"type":"exit","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":1,"onHasSubscribersChange":null},"customscheme":{"type":"customscheme","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":0,"onHasSubscribersChange":null},"message":{"type":"message","handlers":{},"state":0,"fireArgs":null,"numHandlers":0,"onHasSubscribersChange":null}}}}
⚡️  [log] - onscript loading complete
⚡️  WebView loaded
2020-11-07 09:26:24.078843-0500 App[22260:325714] No
2020-11-07 09:26:24.090239-0500 App[22260:325714] didStartProvisionalNavigation
⚡️  [log] - Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
⚡️  [log] - Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 91 ms
⚡️  [warn] - Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.
⚡️  [warn] - Install the StatusBar plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar'
⚡️  [warn] - Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but the SplashScreen plugin is not installed.
⚡️  [warn] - Install the SplashScreen plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen'
2020-11-07 09:26:24.427205-0500 App[22260:325714] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7fa6c450df80>.
⚡️  To Native ->  App addListener 86862752
2020-11-07 09:41:26.240739-0500 App[22260:325714] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
2020-11-07 09:41:26.240903-0500 App[22260:325714] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10cc0ff00 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 22267, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}
```